# Insert google maps autofill address API into mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, google-places

I have been trying for hours now to get this working and would really appreciate help as  i think it's a small typo that i'm blind to. I am creating a search bar for addresses that when someone searches it adds their address to a database, however everytime I search a blank row is added to the database making me think the variables are empty however I cant figure out for the life of me how to fill them.

https://pastebin.com/4CmY1CHt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <?php 

        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $database = 'addressTest';
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);
        if ($con){
            echo 'successfully connected';
        }

      $number = $street = $town = $county = $country = '';

      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $number = $_POST["street_number"];  
        $street = $_POST["route"];
        $town = $_POST["locality"];
        $county = $_POST["administrative_area_level_1"];
        $country = $_POST["country"];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO address (Number, Street, City, State, Country) VALUES ('$number', '$street', '$town', '$county', '$country')";
            $insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if ($insert){
                echo "inserted successfully";     
        }
      }

      ?>

    <div id="locationField">
        <form name=addressField  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
                   onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="address"></input>

    </div>

            <table id="address">
            <tr>
              <td class="label">Street address</td>

              <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" name=street_number
                    disabled="true"></input></td>

              <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
                    disabled="true"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="label">City</td>

              <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
                   You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
                   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
              -->
              <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
                    disabled="true"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="label">State</td>
              <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
                    id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
              <td class="label">Zip code</td>
              <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
                    disabled="true"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="label">Country</td>
              <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
                    id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm()">
      </form>

    <script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(
            {'country': ['irl']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAygtLX9ROxE1TF6RJ9KG6yWJ_zTv5IZG4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated and sorry if it's obvious.

Comment: The only obvious thing for an outsider is to `echo` the `$insert` variable, but I guess you already tried that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the problems

1. All form input fields are without `name` attribute which is necessary for form fields to post
2. remove `disable` attribute, disabled attribute field values are never posted,instead use `readonly` attribute

use `print_r($_POST);` to see what values are being posted after form is submitted.

So here is complete code

```
<body>
  <?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $database = 'addressTest';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);
    if ($con){
        echo 'successfully connected';
    }

  $number = $street = $town = $county = $country = '';



  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  //print_r($_POST); use this to debug POST data 
    $number = $_POST["street_number"];  
    $street = $_POST["route"];
    $town = $_POST["locality"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO address (Number, Street, City, State, Country) VALUES ('$number', '$street', '$town', '$county', '$country')";
        $insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if ($insert){
            echo "inserted successfully";    
    }
  }

  ?>

<div id="locationField">
    <form name=addressField  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
               onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="address"></input>

</div>

        <table id="address">
        <tr>
          <td class="label">Street address</td>

          <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" name="street_number"
                readonly="true"></input></td>

          <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" name="route"
                readonly="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="label">City</td>

          <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
               You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
               https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
          -->
          <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" name="locality"
                readonly="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="label">State</td>
          <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
                id="administrative_area_level_1" readonly="true"></input></td>
          <td class="label">Zip code</td>
          <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" name="postal_code"
                readonly="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="label">Country</td>
          <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
                id="country" name="country"readonly="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm()">
  </form>

<script>
  // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
  // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(
        {'country': ['irl']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAygtLX9ROxE1TF6RJ9KG6yWJ_zTv5IZG4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: thankyou so much. I really appreciate it, was going mad looking at it